# Compressing XML before writing file

Tags: c#, xml, gzip

I'm trying to save a large amount of data to a XML and the file ends up with a very large size. I've searched compression but all examples I found first write the file, then read it to compress to another file, ending with both the large and the compressed files, and the closest I got to removing the intermediate step of writing then reading, ended up with a zip containing an extension-less file(which I can open in notepad as a XML).

this is what I have now:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(@"File.zip"))
{
    using (GZipStream Compress = new GZipStream(outFile, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Compress, settings))
        {
            //write the XML
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make the file inside the zip have the XML extension?

Comment: What you have looks correct.  This appears to compress in-stream.  Is that not what it's doing?  By the way, if the file is "very large," I'd open it in something other than Notepad.

Comment: @harpo opening in notepad was just to see if it was written right, and it is, but the file doesnt have an extension

Comment: The problem is that the contents of the zip file contain an extensionless file named `File`. Is this correct?

Comment: You don't need to give it a name "inside the zip". Just decompress it via a GZip decompressing stream in a very similar way to how you compressed it, and pass the decompressed stream to `XmlReader` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be a little misunderstanding of fundamentals. From what I know, GZip is a compression system, but not an archiving system. When working with UNIX systems, they tend to be treated as two separate things (whereas ZIP or RAR compression does both). Archiving puts a number of files in one file, and compression makes that file smaller.

Have you ever seen Unix packages that are downloaded as "filename.tar.gz"? That's generally the naming format - they took an archive file (filename.tar) and applied GZip compression to it (filename.tar.gz)

Actually, you're technically kind of causing a bit of confusion by naming your file ".zip" (which is a completely different, more commonly-used format). if you want to follow along with UNIX traditions, just name your file "file.xml.gz". If you want to archive it, use a Tar archiving library. Other libraries such as 7-zip's may have simpler compression systems that will do both for you, for instance if you want this file to be a .zip, easily read by people on Windows computers.

Comment: the only detail now is that the compressed file has .xml in its name, but its working and its not important. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write to a temp file first. Take a look at

[DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/gzipstream)